# Error when solving an ODE: The function and its Jacobian must be callable functions

Tags: python, typeerror, odeint

I have a very small piece of code where I try to run an ODE. First, I define some constants and arrays that should be filled with the computed values from the for loop. I define a function where the equation is inside, and as I run the code I get a

error: The function and its Jacobian must be callable functions.

It shows me line 17 as the problem.

I tried defining my variables differently so there would be no problem with the float Typeerror that was mentioned earlier, but it did not help. Now I am just not sure what the error message actually means.

```
tOut = np.linspace(t0,tmax,33)
t = tOut[0] #starting point

K = 0.17
r = 3.25
k = 0.24
P = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
d_P_dt = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])

P0 = 1
def fun(K,r,k,tOut): 
    for i in np.arange(0, 33):
        d_P_dt[i] = (K-k)*P[i]
        d_P_dt[i+1] = P[i]
        return d_P_dt

yx = spi.odeint(fun(K,r,k,tOut),P0,tOut)
```

Comment: You have to pass the function itself, not the output of the function. So you need to pass `fun`, not `fun(K,r,k,tOut)`.

Comment: @alkasm if I pass ```fun``` instead of ```fun(K,r,k,tOut)```  I get an error saying ```TypeError: fun() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'k' and 'tOut'```, and if I only add ```k``` and ```tOut``` I keep getting the same error message

Answer (score 0):

[Odeint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) expects a function handle which is simply the name of your function `fun` and an array of function arguments. So the integration call should be:`yx = spi.odeint(fun,P0,tOut)`, where `P0 = np.array([K, r, k])`. Therefore, the correct code should look like :

```
P0 = np.array([K,r,k])
def fun(parameters,t):
    K,r,k = parameters[0], parameters[1],parameters[2]
    for i in np.arange(0, 33):
        d_P_dt[i] = (K-k)*P[i]
        d_P_dt[i+1] = P[i]
        return d_P_dt

yx = spi.odeint(fun,P0,tOut)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read the [odeint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) documention, you are using it wrong. In order to pass arguments to the function you have to put them in the `args` parameter inside of odeint, some like this `odeint(fun,P0,tOut,args = (K,r,k,))`. That is way your code in giving you the Jacobian error. I have cleaned a little bit your code so this should work

```
import scipy as spi
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np

t0 = 0
tmax = 2
tOut = np.linspace(t0,tmax,33)

K = 0.17
r = 3.25
k = 0.24

P0 = 1
def fun(P,K,r,k,t): 
        d_P_dt = (K-k)*P
        return d_P_dt

P = odeint(fun,P0,tOut,args = (K,r,k,))
```

if you want also dPdt you can get it using `dP_dt = (K-k)*P`.